# Capture consent (opt-in/out) via an interactive action embedded in an email message

Tags: consent-management

Is there any recommended way how to implement consent capture via email? I mean a very basic scenario, where somebody just clicks yes/no in auto-generated email, and this information is stored in Salesforce.

I was doing some research, but most of the packages are focused only on displaying the consent, like the one from Salesforce Labs:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMiVQUA1

But is there any way to put an interactive action in an email that could simply translate to one of the standard consent objects? Or is it needed to prepare a custom Apex that leverages `Consent Write API`?

Thank you in advance for any feedback

Comment: To do what you're after, you need to buy Marketing Cloud or Pardot. In the non-Marketing "core" product universe of SF, delivering the end-to-end experience to the users implies building it yourself.

Comment: @identigral, thank you for the feedback. I'm aware of that, but at this point, I just need the simplest possible solution for a small company.

Answer (score 1):

In order to update consent in Salesforce you could try one of these mechanisms to design your solution:

1. Navigate user to web portal which can then make an API call to
   Salesforce
2. Implement Apex email service which to process inbound email which
   can update consent based certain key words in the email.
3. Navigate the user to a Lightning Community Form

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you can use is to have 2 site pages, 1 for accepting and 1 for rejecting. Expose these 2 site page URLs as HTML buttons in your email template and then use Consent Write APIs to manipulate the data. Record info such as Record-Id can be part of the site page URL parameter in an encrypted format.

On the site page, load shows them a confirmation message that their response is captured and thank them for the time.